# Nouveau, but not Nvidia driver working on Ubuntu 20.04 external GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Edit 9/6 0820Zulu:
Addition 9/7: **The sad state of Nvidia with all its money:** These are not acquired quirks, but **a fresh install of 20.04 on the NUC (as well as a seasoned 18.04 w/ 460 driver on a different machine) show these BUGS!** They simply don't hit on a vanilla install.

`sudo chmod 666 /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot` 664 not enuf to write; with 666 it CAN write `last_gfx_boot`.

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-470 /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-470-server` - Add SymLink to account for directory bug.

`sudo touch /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported` as it wanted to create it but couldn't.
`sudo chmod 666 /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported` in case it wanted some file content.
On next boot some process was able to delete the file but the next one couldn't create it again.
`I couldn't open last_gfx_boot for writing.`

Stuck.

Sth seriously ****** up with permissions + the path bug.

Edit 9/5: Moved non-essential irks to the bottom.
@Nmath Edited to have the whole current config in one place, structured:

Don't ask me what I read and tried to get the Nvidia driver (470, latest) working on

- Intel NUC6i7KYK i915 integrated GPU and Ubuntu 20.04
- FHD monitor on the NUC's HDMI
- RTX 2070 in an HP GA1-10 Thunderbolt 3 case
- UHD 49" display (Samsung 2021 TV) on RTXes HDMI

BTW: Secure boot is off. (as suggested in other solutions and didn't make a difference)

With the Nouveau driver (and on Windows 10) the 2nd, UHD display works.

With the Nvidia 470 driver there is no second moni in Display Settings and the TV says "no signal".

After weeks of reading up and digging I'd hope I came across the right info now to solve it.

gpu-manager (edited to exclude AMD as it's N/A):

```
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:193b
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1f02
BusID "PCI:9@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
can't access /etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override file
Found json file: /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-470-server/supported-gpus.json
File /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-470-server/supported-gpus.json not found
Warning: access to PME Capabilities was denied
Is nvidia runtime pm supported for "0x1f02"? no
Checking power status in /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:09:00.0/power
Runtime D3 status:          ?
Is nvidia runtime pm enabled for "0x1f02"? no
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
...
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-DP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 1
I couldn't open /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot for writing.
Error: can't write to /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
```

On further digging today, 9/5:
`/etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override` really not there.

Correction: Re json file - guess bug: `nvidia-driver-470-server` directory is NOT there as I installed 470 w/o "server" in the name.
So there is a `nvidia-driver-470/supported-gpus.json`.

Worth trying a SYLK?

Also, `nvidia-xconfig` says there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and generates one.

**A thousand thanks in advance for a solution!**
G.

**Non-essential itches:**
On Ubuntu first some unrecoverable NUC firmware bug got in the way (Not on Windows!), but there is no newer BIOS.

Finally with an FHD display on internal HDMI and the UHD on the Thunderbolt 3 I discovered a boot problem, cuz boot from TB was on in the BIOS and the system was stuck waiting for TB boot when on.

Windows 10 has been working in ALL configurations! (I could circumvent the TB boot problem by switching on the external GPU with Win already up. Didn't figure the reason as long as I had only the UHD display on the internal HDMI and used the GPU as machine learning accelerator.)

Comment: You should include complete details about what it took to get where you are right now. We can't really advise or problem solve when we don't know the full history. It's also unclear what hardware you are actually using. How is the GPU connected externally?

Comment: My runtime D3 status on a GTX 970 hanging off an expresscard slot is "Disabled by default".  Pretty much the same output otherwise. otherwise. Just using laptop display, not a second monitor from the card, which did work when tested.